# Return number of rows affected in @Query UPDATE in java spring boot repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, repository

this is my query:

```java
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE tb_pessoal_funcionarios SET salario = CAST(salario(salario* :percentualAumento)/100 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) "
                + "WHERE id IN (:funcionarioId) "
                + "AND (:alterarFuncionariosDemitidos IS true OR condicao <> 'Inativo')")
void AlterarSalarioSelecionadosPorPercentual(Double percentualAumento, Long funcionarioId, Boolean alterarFuncionariosDemitidos);
```

In the case as I'm starting now in this area, I need some help. Att;

Comment: Just set the return type of your method to `int`; it will automatically return the number of rows affected by the update.

Comment: and what would be the best way for me to get this return?